# if values from one array matches ANY values from another return true

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, match

I have the jQuery below and when the input values (in array) match the html of .adiv (in array) I get an alert which says true, BUT this only happens if the exactly ALL the values from the two arrays match. what i am trying to do is if ALL of the values from the temp array match ANY of the values from the divar array return true. so for eg. if the .adiv html is `this is a div` and the input value is `this div` return true `is div` return true etc, however if the input value is `thisisadiv` or for eg `isa div` OR `random words` return false. **ALSO** if the temp array contains a word not in the divar array it should return false

### http://jsfiddle.net/7Q4CJ/

```
jQuery.fn.compare = function(t) {
    if (this.length != t.length) { return false; }
    var a = this.sort(),
        b = t.sort();
    for (var i = 0; t[i]; i++) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) { 
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
$("button").click(function() {

    var inputstr = $(".searchval").val().replace(/ /g, ",");
    var temp = new Array();
    temp = inputstr.split(",");

    var dival = $(".adiv").html().replace(/ /g, ",");
    var divar = new Array();
    divar = dival.split(",");

    alert($(temp).compare(divar)); 
});
```

​

Comment: `compare` expects identicality (after sorting) not similarity.

Comment: it's meant to for that...i need to change it to find similarity instead

Comment: OK, I understand. See belated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After several domestic interruptions ....*

jQuery's `.each()` in combination with `.inArray()` can help make the code reasonably concise.

Sticking with the original concept of a `.compare()` plugin, I get this:

```
jQuery.fn.compare = function(t) {
    var match = true;
    this.each(function(i, word) {
        if($.inArray(word, t) === -1) {
            match = false;
            return false;//equivalent to break
        }
    });
   return match;
};
```

And here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q4CJ/6/).

Comment: for your example you need to enter the entire exact string to return "true"

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/nandu8201/SsSna/1/

Guess that should be enough.  If false you will get -1 and if true you will get 0

Comment: no.... because if i enter 'this div' i get -1 when it should be true/ in your  case 0+

Comment: even then when i enter div it retruns -1

Comment: I din't notice I was playing with binary digits :) .. my bad .. try this .. it should work!!
http://jsfiddle.net/nandu8201/SsSna/14/

Comment: btw .. its 1 for true and 0 for false just in case you don't notice the change

Answer (score 0):

or the one line version using underscore.js:

```
jQuery.fn.compare(t){
    _.any(this, function(item){ return _.indexOf(t, item) !== -1; });
}
```